# Setting title and labels in alertifyjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, alert

I have created a custom confirm dialog using alertifyjs and am trying to set the labels and title, however, I can't seem to achieve both at once. Please can someone help.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/css/alertify.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="display:none;">
    <div id="dlgContent">
      <p> Enter Value One </p>
      <input class="ajs-input" id="inpOne" type="text" value="Input One Default Value" />

      <p> Enter Value Two </p>
      <input class="ajs-input" id="inpTwo" type="text" value="Input two default Value" />

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- the script  -->

  <script>
    var dlgContentHTML = $('#dlgContent').html();

    $('#dlgContent').html("");
    alertify.confirm(dlgContentHTML).set('onok', function(closeevent, value) {
      var inpOneVal = $('#inpOne').val();
      var inpTwoVal = $('#inpTwo').val();
      //updateListItems(inpOneVal,inpTwoVal); 

      if (inpOneVal == "test" && inpTwoVal == "test") {
        alertify.success('Successful');
      } else {
        alertify.error('Wrong')

      }
    }).set({title:"Update"},{labels:{ok:'Forward', cancel: 'Backward'}});
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is how I have attempted

```
...}).set({title:"Update"},{labels:{ok:'Forward', cancel: 'Backward'}});
```

Please can someone tell me how I can achieve this because I want to set custom title and title for the dialog box. I been on the documentation but wasn't able to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong

Change

**`.set({title:"Update"},{labels:{ok:'Forward', cancel: 'Backward'}});`**

to

**`.set({title:"Update"}).set({labels:{ok:'Forward', cancel: 'Backward'}});`**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/css/alertify.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="display:none;">
    <div id="dlgContent">
      <p> Enter Value One </p>
      <input class="ajs-input" id="inpOne" type="text" value="Input One Default Value" />

      <p> Enter Value Two </p>
      <input class="ajs-input" id="inpTwo" type="text" value="Input two default Value" />

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- the script  -->

  <script>
    var dlgContentHTML = $('#dlgContent').html();

    $('#dlgContent').html("");
    alertify.confirm(dlgContentHTML).set('onok', function(closeevent, value) {
      var inpOneVal = $('#inpOne').val();
      var inpTwoVal = $('#inpTwo').val();
      //updateListItems(inpOneVal,inpTwoVal); 

      if (inpOneVal == "test" && inpTwoVal == "test") {
        alertify.success('Successful');
      } else {
        alertify.error('Wrong')

      }
    }).set({title:"Update"}).set({labels:{ok:'Forward', cancel: 'Backward'}});
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I need to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer but I have up voted in meanwhile :)

Comment: @Jackie Welcome

Comment: Can you see if your able to help on this please (I am trying to achieve the layout in edited section) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515837/creating-overlay-in-css-grid

Comment: Also this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232563/text-area-with-upload-attachments-options-html-jquery

Comment: Also do you know if its possible to remove border/back from the buttons on the alertiifyJS dialog box and instead have only text e.g., forward and backward

Comment: @Jackie may be you need to override the button default css.You can create new question for this issue

Comment: Sure i can try creating new question for this. Do you have any idea on the other 2 please?

Comment: @Jackie- Updated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515837/creating-overlay-in-css-grid